# Кастомизация listview c#

Tags: c#, listview

Пишу клиент для вк. Список друзей хочу выводить в формате: картинка и label. Сделал свой элемент управления, как сделать так, чтобы его можно было добавить в listview, Или чтобы элементы listview были в том формате который я хочу? Пишу на простых формах, без wpf и всего такого.

Comment: А вот и зря, что без WPF. Как не крути, но дизайн - это априори WPF. Пару строк WPF заменяет кучу кода WinForms. Хотите дизайн - переходите, мой вам совет....

Comment: Дело в том, что я пишу курсовик, и так как нам его поздно выдали, мне не хватит времени чтобы разобраться с WPF. К тому же я там вообще ничего не понял)

Comment: Он очень легкий, если хорошо знаете WinForms, то освоение WPF займет довольно мало времени

Comment: Вы бы показали свой элемент управления. Вообще, используйте `TableLayoutPanel` или `FlowLayoutPanel` вместо `ListView`.